# Haskell - Prevent ambiguous occurrence of + for instances of a certain class?

Tags: haskell

I'm new at Haskell, and I'm having a problem. I have the following

```
class Operation a where
    evaluate :: a -> Float

data Value = Value {value :: Float} deriving Show
instance Operation Value where
    evaluate = value

(+) :: (Operation a, Operation b) => a -> b -> (a, b)
(+) x y = (x, y)
```

If I run `(Value 3) Main.+ (Value 5)` everything works as intended. However `(Value 3) + (Value 5)` gives an ambiguous error. This makes sense because this is a redefinition of `(+)`.

I want ghci to choose Main.+ every time the types are instances of the class Operation, and choose Prelude.+ when they are not. There should be no ambiguity here, because a given type either is an instance of the class or it isn't. How can I write this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, there is no mechanism to check the negative condition "this type is NOT a member of this class". This is because type class instances can be added to any module at all, so to check the negative GHC would need to read all the modules, and recompile everything every time an instance is added.

You should either rename your operator to something else, or hide the `Prelude.+` import (keeping it accessible with a qualified module import). In the latter case, you'll need to use `Prelude.+` for the standard operator.

Some other options exist, leveraging overlapping instances, but I'm not sure they would be a good idea to use here.